# Centos 7 kernel loading custom monitor EDID file does not work

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, xorg, xrandr, edid

I want to load a custom EDID File with the Linux Kernel.
I added `drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/myedid.bin` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/defauls/grub`. Then I updated the grub.cfg with `grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and added the EDID File to initrd with `dracut --force --include /usr/lib/firmware/edid /usr/lib/firmware/edid`
I checked with `lsinitrd` if the files are there

```
   lsinitrd | grep edid
    Arguments: --force --include '/usr/lib/firmware/edid' '/usr/lib/firmware/edid'
    drwxrwx---   2 root     root            0 Oct  6 01:25 usr/lib/firmware/edid
```

Then I restarted the computer and xrandr gives the old informations and not the infomations I defined in EDID File.

```
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is what dmesg | grep drm prints out (I also tried out to change drm_kms_firmware to drm but this only removed the warning in the log. I am using kernelversion 3.10 so drm_kms_helper should be right):

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=XXXXX ro drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/myedid.bin rhgb quiet mem=2G

[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=2df6baad-7c38-488e-8acd-14a461e72a99 ro drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/myedid.bin rhgb quiet

[    2.652804] [drm] drm_kms_firmware.edid_firmware is deprecated, please use drm.edid_firmware intead.

[    3.115696] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver

[    3.117295] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).

[    3.117299] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.

[    3.179723] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20181204 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0

[    3.198830] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device

[    3.261252] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
```

This is my intel.conf inside /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-intel.conf
Section "Device"

  Identifier "intel(0)"
  Driver "intel"

  Option "TearFree" "true"
  Option "DRI" "2"
  Option "ReprobeOutputs" "true"
  Option "HotPlug" "false"
EndSection
```

And my Xorg log (grep drm)

```
[    96.089] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=XXXXX ro drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/myedid.bin rhgb quiet
[    96.098] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    96.098] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
```

Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64

In Kernel config this is set

```
CONFIG_DRM_LOAD_EDID_FIRMWARE=y
```